# Deriving TypeScript interface from object literal

Tags: typescript

Does TypeScript have the ability to infer an interface from an object literal? Like the following:

```
export const theme = {
  primaryColor: "#e9e9eb",
  secondaryColor: "blue"
};
```

The interface would be the following, which (AFAICT), TypeScript compels me to create a separate interface for, but I would like to automatically derive.

```
export interface IThemeInterface {
  primaryColor: string;
  secondaryColor: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`type IThemeInterface = typeof theme;` does the correct thing here.